# Primefaces drag and drop from p:tree to p:datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to figure out how to drop a node from p:tree do p:datatable.
My configuration is primefaces 6.1, myfaces 2.2.12.

Is this possible? I passed thru all tutorials, examples..and didnt see how to do it.

Comment: Why not creating your own transforming method ?!? in the  [Drag and drop Primefaces example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/dragdrop.xhtml) there is an ajax event **dragdrop** and in the listner ajax event you reuse your tree element to a new dataTable row. see more [DragDrop - Draggable](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/draggable.xhtml)

Comment: Yes it is possible in a way, at least I think it is. I do drag-drop from a datatable to a treetable. It requires custom code and some creativity. It unfortunately is too complex to try to write an answer for your case in the limited amount of free time I have.